# SQL Server uses all memory (RAM)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, memory, ram, database-administration

I start receiving high memory usage alerts  so I have to restart the production server almost every night. Otherwise, all memory (RAM) gets used by SQL Server.
The server has 64 GB RAM and SQL has about 58 GB allocated.
I’m curious as to what is causing the SQL Server to use up all RAM.
The maximum server memory is set up for 58000 MB.But at the end of the day, the server start working really slow. So I have to reboot it every night.
I am receiving high memory usage warning from Nagious:
[image]

I did my observation for a couple of days without rebooting the server, and this is what I got:
Buffer_Page_Count and Buffer_Pool  are increasing, also Clean_Page and Dirty_Page count. 
But I am not sure what is that mean? From that, how can I find out where is my memory goes?
[image]

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory

Comment: That's the way SQL Server is designed: in order to increate its performance, it will use up as much memory as it can get - or as much as you let it get.

Comment: The default install of SQL Server configures it to use all RAM. Reconfigure to not use all RAM

Comment: But I did. Maximum server memory I put 58000 MB. Is any other ways to reconfigure?
It gets to the point that the server starts to work sluggish, so I have to reboot it every day.

Comment: @Oleg  How much RAM does your server have in total?

Comment: @Iamdave. The server has 64 GB RAM and SQL has about 58 GB allocated.  Thanks

Comment: What is stopping you from simply lowering the SQL allocation?  It will use all the memory you give it to aid performance.  Give it 58GB and it'll use 58GB.  Give it 45GB and it'll use 45GB, leaving the rest to anything else installed on the server, like Windows.

Comment: I can lower the SQL allocation, but when I got an alert on Saturday night, SQL server was using 48 GB and nothing else on a server was even close.
This doesnt happens on any of our other SQL servers.

Comment: I don’t get an alert on Friday night after a full day of production usage.  The alert first occurs on Saturday night, after relatively light usage on Saturday.  Why would that be?

Comment: It's normal for SQL to use up it's allocated RAM. If it didn't use it then that expensive RAM would go to waste. So from my perspective, it's not a problem that it uses its RAM. Where do you get the alert from (please post it), and what do you mean by sluggish? SQL runs sluggish or OS interaction is sluggish? Does anything else run on this server besides SQL?